If $K/F$ and $K'/F'$ are field extensions and $\varphi :F\to F'$ and $\psi:K\to K'$ are (possibly distinct) isomorphisms, then must $[K':F'] = [K:F]$?
I think the answer is no for the following reason. Let $\mathcal B = \{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$ be an $F$-basis for $K$. Then the only natural way I can think of to relate $\mathcal B$ to a set of $n$ vectors in $K'$ is to define $b_i' = \psi(b_i)$ and $\mathcal B' = \{b_1', \dots, b_n'\}$. But I see no reason why $\mathcal B'$ should be an $F'$-basis for $K'$. For instance, it might not span since, given $\psi(x) \in K'$,
$$\psi(x) = \psi\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n f_ib_i\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \psi(f_i)\psi(b_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \psi(f_i)b_i'$$
where the $f_i$ are the coordinates of $x$ wrt $\mathcal B$. But unless each $\psi(f_i)\in F'$, this doesn't express $\psi(x)$ as an $F'$-linear-combination of $\mathcal B'$.
Am I correct, and if so what is a counterexample?

This is an example with $F=F'$ and $\varphi=\mathrm{id}$. Or you can modify to take $K=\mathbb{Q}(x^4)$, F=\mathbb{Q}(x)$, $K'=\mathbb{Q}(x^6)$, $F'=\mathbb{Q}(x^2)$.

In other words, take $F=F'=K=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ with $\varphi=\mathrm{id}$, $K'=\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$. Then $[K:F]=1$, $[K':F']=2$, and $F\cong F'\cong K\cong K'$.
